# A representation of natural numbers with a limited number of terms?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Define $\;a,b,c:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N\;$ by 
$\;n=a(n)\cdot b(n)+c(n)$, where 
$\;b(n)\leq a(n)\leq 3b(n)\;$ and $c(n)$ is minimal for choices of $a(n)$ and $b(n)$. Does it exist 
$\;N\in\mathbb N\;$ such that $\forall n\in\mathbb N:k>N\implies c^k(n)=0\;$, where $\;c^1(n)=c(n)\;$ and $\;c^{m+1}(n)=c(c^m(n))$?

---

Due to Lagranges four square theorem all natural numbers can be represented by four squares. This question is about an eventual representation of all natural numbers as a N-limited sum of certain rectangle areas.

---

Comment: By "$c(n)$ is minimal for choices of $a(n)$ and $b(n)$", do you mean that the values of $a(n)$ and $b(n)$ are chosen specifically to minimize $c(n)$?

Comment: @JasonM, yes and as far as I can see that uniquely determines $a(n)$ and $b(n)$.

Comment: Why did you define $c(n)$?  Why not just ask "For each $n\in \Bbb{N}$, does there exist $a_i, b_i \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $n=a_1b_1+a_2b_2+\ldots+a_kb_k$ for some fixed $k$, satisfying $b_i \leq a_i \leq 3b_i$ for all $i$"?  It seems more straight to the point.

Comment: @JasonM. But that's a consequence of the theorem of Lagrange. My formulation is about a certain choice of the rectangles.

Comment: I guess I'm still wondering about the motivation for this problem.  If representing $n$ as a sum of rectangles with the $b_i\leq a_i \leq 3b_i$ condition was your goal, then there just seems to be a simpler way of stating it, and as you pointed out, it clearly follows from Lagrange's Theorem.